# Query on date part of Timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return 2 columns for a graph on with date and the other with count of jobs for the date.
Jobdate is a timestamp however. So although the first query is instant, it will give a new row for every time change as well.

```
 SELECT JOBDATE ,COUNT(JOBNO) AS TOTAL FROM JOB 
 where JOBDATE > '2022-09-20'
 GROUP BY JOBDATE
  ORDER BY JOBDATE
```

The query below works fine except that it takes 30 seconds to run over a small dataset.

```
 SELECT CAST(JOBDATE AS DATE)  AS THEDATE,COUNT(JOBNO) AS TOTAL FROM JOB 
 where CAST(JOBDATE AS DATE) > '2022-09-20'
 GROUP BY THEDATE
  ORDER BY THEDATE
```

On option is to have a second JOBDATE date only field. Has anyone got a better idea?

Comment: "it takes 30 seconds to run over a small dataset" - what does the execution plan of that query tell you about this? As you haven't shared the table structure: which indexes do you currently use?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. For anyone one else who needs to know -

```
SELECT date(JOBDATE) ,COUNT(JOBNO) AS TOTAL 
FROM JOB 
where JOBDATE > '2022-09-20'
GROUP BY date(JOBDATE)
```

Comment: SOme description of why you think this change made a difference is always more than useful in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume the casts are causing the slowdown. They are replaced with date() and is much better

Comment: Please share more details. How did you "assume" that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).